# Why can't I match on a Seq.empty?

Tags: scala

I tried matching a seq like this:

```
val users: Seq[User] = ....

users match {
  case Seq.empty => ....
  case ..
}
```

I got an error saying:

```
stable identifier required, but scala.this.Predef.Set.empty found.
```

Can someone explain why I can't do this? i.e. the theory behind it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both `Seq.apply` and `Seq.empty` are implemented in [GenericCompanion](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/generic/GenericCompanion.scala#L1), which has no `unapply` method, so you'd think that pattern matching wouldn't be possible, but you're still able to pattern match on `Seq()` because `Seq.unapplySeq()`, implemented in [SeqFactory](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/generic/SeqFactory.scala#L1), makes that available.

From the `unapplySeq()` docs:

> This method is called in a pattern match { case Seq(...) => }.

**more background**

Collections make pattern matching possible via the `unapplySeq()` method, which gets called when the compiler sees something like `case List() => ...`.

It's interesting that `List(42)` is the same thing as `List.apply(42)` but not so in pattern matching:

```
lst match {
  case List(8)       => ...  // OK
  case List.apply(8) => ...  // won't compile
}
```

The same principle applies to `Seq()` and `Seq.empty`.

Comment: So it isn't really accurate to say that `Seq.empty` is a method?

Comment: @evan058, `Seq.empty` is a method but so is `Seq.apply`.  After running a few tests I've added some details.

Comment: Seq.empty isn't a partial function, that is the reason no?

Comment: @coolbreeze, `Seq.empty` **is** a partial function. You can call `isDefinedAt()` on it or `runWith()` or any of the other pf methods. Try this `Seq.empty[Int] match {case _: PartialFunction[_,_] => true}` and see what you get. No, the reason `Seq()` matches but `Seq.empty` doesn't is because the `unapplySeq()` method gets called when the compiler sees the former but no the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Match on `Seq()` or `Nil` instead:

```
scala> Seq.empty
res0: Seq[Nothing] = List()

scala> val a = Seq(1,2,3)
a: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val b = Seq()
b: Seq[Nothing] = List()

scala> a match {case Seq() => "empty"
     | case _ => "other"
     | }
res1: String = other

scala> b match {case Seq() => "empty"
     | case _ => "other"
     | }
res2: String = empty
```

See [@jwvh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41474754/2661491) for technical reasons why.

Comment: so its a value vs method reason?

Comment: Partially, but also because you don't want to match on something with type `() => Seq()` (if you use an eta expansion), you want to match on `Seq()`

Comment: @coolbreeze See [@jwvh's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41474754/2661491) for a better explanation.